# How to solve constraint problems without Lagrange multipliers?

Tags: maxima-minima, differential-forms, lagrange-multiplier

I have a problem of determining the maximum volume of a cuboid inscribed in an elipsoid.

I would like to solve it without Lagrange multipliers.

I have the function $f = 8xyz$ representing the volume of the cuboid and the elipsoid constraint efoution $g = \dfrac{x^2}{a}+\dfrac{y^2}{b}+\dfrac{z^2}{c}=1$

I've tried $df\wedge dg=0$, but I get an unsolvable set of equations :

z=c/b y

z=c/a x

y=b/a x

Can this even be solved with this differential form approach?

I just took the differentials of f and g so that

df = 8dx yz + 8 dy xz + 8dz xy

and similarly for dg then just took the outer product.

Or do I have to find the multipliers explicitly?

Comment: Note that solving $df\wedge dg=0$ is *precisely* doing Lagrange multipliers without the $\lambda$. Edit your post to include the “nonsense set of equations.”

Comment: Isnt lamba the multiplier? My point was that, to do this without having to calculate lambda, I'll add the equations I got. I'm not very good with coordinate /multi variable forms.

Comment: You never have to calculate the multiplier. Many books do this badly. Just eliminate $\lambda$ by taking ratios (with a little worrying about denominators vanishing). These are the same equations you have if you use basic algebra.

Comment: Can I solve it with the outer product of Diff forms?

Comment: And dos dx ^dx vanish then?

Comment: Yes. And $dx\wedge dy = -dy\wedge dx$. You might find some of my YouTube lectures — linked in my profile — helpful. Your equations are incorrect.

Comment: @SineoftheTime Please don't make mathematical changes when editing unless you are sure of what you're doing. You removed the wedge product, which was the whole point of the post.

Comment: I re edited that, yea I know the basics that the differential anti commute hence their squares vanish, but I don't know where I went wrong, I'd apprechiete at least some pointers

Comment: Sorry, my bad .

Comment: After all this, you should edit to have the constraint $g=1$. I think this missing $1$ was a good part of your confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to expand on my comments because I hope this will be helpful not only to you, but also to others. I won't work out all the algebra to actually solve the problem.

You have
\begin{align*}
df &= 8(yz\,dx + xz\,dy + xy\,dz) \quad\text{and}\\
dg &= 2\left(\frac xa dx + \frac yb dy + \frac zc dz\right).
\end{align*}

Thus, using skew-commutativity of wedge product,
$$\frac1{16} df\wedge dg = \big(\frac{y^2z}b-\frac{x^2z}a\big)dx\wedge dy + \big(\frac{yz^2}c-\frac{x^2y}a\big)dx\wedge dz + \big(\frac{xz^2}c-\frac{xy^2}b\big)dy\wedge dz.$$
Since $dx\wedge dy$, $dx\wedge dz$, and $dy\wedge dz$ are linearly independent, in order to have $df\wedge dg=0$, all three coefficients must vanish, and we get the system of equations
\begin{align*}
z(ay^2-bx^2) &= 0,\\
y(az^2-cx^2) &= 0,\\
x(bz^2-cy^2) &= 0.
\end{align*}

Where did you get $df\wedge dg = 0$? Well, this equation expresses the fact that $df$ and $dg$ become linearly dependent at the desired points. This is equivalent to the classical statement that $\nabla f$ and $\nabla g$ become linearly dependent, hence scalar multiples. Since the overriding assumption is that $\nabla g\ne 0$ on the constraint set, this is equivalent to the condition that $\nabla f=\lambda\nabla g$ for some scalar $\lambda$. How does the usual solution go?

We have
$$\nabla f = 8(yz,xz,xy) \quad\text{and}\quad \nabla g = 2\big(\frac xa,\frac yb,\frac zc\big).$$
Saying that $\nabla f =\lambda \nabla g$ says (I'm ignoring the numerical factors by replacing $\lambda$ with $4\lambda$)
$$yz = \lambda\frac xa, \quad xz = \lambda\frac yb, \quad xy = \lambda \frac zc.$$
Now we eliminate $\lambda$ by taking ratios. Assume for the moment none of $x,y,z$ is $0$.
$$(\lambda = )\frac{yz}{\frac xa} = \frac{xz}{\frac yb} = \frac{xy}{\frac zc},$$
or
$$\frac{ayz}x = \frac{bxz}y = \frac{cxy}z.\tag{$\star$}$$
By cross-multiplying we obtain
$$ay^2z=bx^2z, \quad ayz^2=cx^2y, \quad bxz^2=cxy^2.$$
Look familiar? (By cross-multiplying, in this case, we get the equations that allow the denominators to be $0$, and those are indeed cases we would check separately if we stopped at ($\star$) to work with the equations. For example, the first gives $z=0$ or $a\frac yx = b\frac xy$.)

In summary, the two approaches are identical. In notation that is used various places in the world, we replace $\nabla f\times\nabla g = 0$ (which, in $\Bbb R^3$, is one way of saying the two vectors are linearly dependent) with $\nabla f\wedge\nabla g = 0$, and this corresponds to the dual statement $df\wedge dg=0$.

Comment: I got that same set of equations but I divided out the z in the first and other first exponent variables in the other 2 equations.

Comment: I still can't solve that set of 3 equations lol, that's why I asked the question I got to those 3 equations and I thought I missed something lol. How does that set have a solution I get x= cx

Comment: Now you know why most people put $a^2$, etc,

Comment: Oh yea lol thanks

Comment: But are you sure those 3 equations can be solved , I know it's an idiotic question lol but I can't solve them.

Comment: PS nice book on Diff geo

Comment: So if you play with the equations, you get $abz^2=acy^2=bcx^2$, which means $\frac{x^2}a = \frac{y^2}b = \frac{z^2}c$, as expected.

Comment: But the Point is to find x, y, and z in terms of a, b, and c for which the volume is maximal. It should be x = a sqrt(3), y= bsqrt(3)

Comment: You need to review solving max/min problems! You need to use the constraint equation, no?

Comment: This the max problem and g is the constraint. What am I missing. F is the volume with side 2x 2y 2z,

Comment: Have you used the constraint?

Comment: I thought that I could just do the procedure you did, I got to the same 3 equations and then I got stuck and asked the question cause I thought that the procedure above is in fact using the constraint.

Comment: Use it now to solve for $x,y,z$.

Comment: Oh I got it now thanks.

Comment: I just noticed your constraint equation is missing an equality. It’s $g=1$!!

Answer (score 1):

The Lagrange multipliers can be avoided by eliminating the restriction. Making $y = \lambda x, z = \mu x$ we have

$$
\max_{x,y,z} f= x^3 \lambda \mu\ \ \ \text{s. t.}\ \ \ x^2\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{\lambda^2}{b}+\frac{\mu^2}{c}\right) = g
$$

or the equivalent unconstrained problem

$$
\max_{\lambda,\mu}\frac{g^{\frac 32}\lambda \mu}{\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{\lambda^2}{b}+\frac{\mu^2}{c}\right)^{\frac 32}}
$$

Comment: I though I could just do the derivation that I did and I got to the same pint as the first answer and  got stuck there because I though the procedure would give me the values for the sides such that the volume is maximal.